# while body.onload is false = function

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get something like this:

```
while(body.onload == false) {
  alert("please wait content is loading");
}
```

I want to display a message like "please wait" until my pictures are loaded from a website.

How can I do that?

Comment: There is no need to add the tags to the title.

Answer (score 4):

When you start loading the pictures, make an overlay visible. Once the pictures have loaded (you'll have some sort of callback for it, most likely), hide it again.

Comment: how can i query that? they are just embedded like src="http://example.com/picture1.png"

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing it with jquery using the following code:

```
 $(window).load(function () {
 $('#pictures').fadeIn();
 $('#loading_text_please_wait').fadeOut();
 });
```

thanks for the answers